# how to convert .cer to .pfx programatically using Java

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pfx

I used bouncy castle and JSCEP to create my certificate. Now i have my private key and .cer certificate. I would now need to create pfx or p12 file out of this using Java or Bouncy castle.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Java [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html) class, and how to get an instance of it with the `PKCS12` keystore type.

Then look at the [setKeyEntry()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#setKeyEntry%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20java.security.cert.Certificate%5B%5D%29) and [store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20char%5B%5D%29).  That should give you a very good start to achieving your goal.

Comment: Thanks Gtrig for sharing your inputs. I will try out this